# Unselecting the table column when ever Sorting happens

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I have an Application which loads an Table on click of an button, currently for the table Sorting option has been removed, But when ever I click on any column and then Click on Table Header , the selected Column should get de-selected. Not sure how to achieve this.

Thanks in Advance!!!!

Answer (score 1):

You have to trigger 'buttonSelected:' method :)

```
 @interface ViewController () <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSIndexPath *currentSelectedIndexPath;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

#pragma mark - UIViewControllerDelegate

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didDeselectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.currentSelectedIndexPath = nil;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    self.currentSelectedIndexPath = indexPath;
}

- (IBAction)buttonSelected:(UIButton *)sender {
    [self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:self.currentSelectedIndexPath animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Comment: Thanks for the Answer!!!...Just one more doubt, can it be any way done through XIB?Do we need to use DataSource and Delegate methods only?